# 17.10: Intel UHD 630 (8700k) unable to boot

Tags: nvidia, xorg, intel-graphics, intel

I have a pc equipped with an intel 8700k cpu and an nvidia 1070

When my monitor is connected to the 1070, everything is fine

When my monitor is connected to the iGPU (intel UHD 630), it is unable to finish booting. It starts printing the startup info in the terminal, but stops here:

```
Started Session 1 of user MyUser
Started User Manager for UID 1000
Created slice User Slice of gdm
Starting User manager for UID 121
Started session c1 of user gdm
Started user manager for UID 121
Stopping User manager for UID 121
Stopped User manager for UID 121
Removed slice User Slice of gdm
Created slice User slice of gdm
...
Started session c2 of user gdm
Started session c3 of user gdm
...
Starting Update UTMP about system runlevel changes
Started update UTMP about system runlevel changes.erface
```

Gdm/X never starts. I can switch tty, but am unable to start x

I tried updating the kernel to 4.14.1 but this gives me the same result

When i boot using the nvidia card instead and go to "additional drivers" i can see both the 1070 and the iGPU (iGPU using proprietery intel-microcode) but the device is listed as "UNKNOWN"

How do i get X to output on my iGPU?

Edit:
From Xorg.log:

```
LoadKernelModule: Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed (WW) LoadKernelModule: Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed intel: waited 202 ms for i915.ko driver to load
LoadKernelModule: Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed (EE) No devices detected
```

Comment: `intel-microcode` is not a driver and not even related to graphics, it's updated firmware for (Intel) CPUs. Intel Graphics drivers are (should be) installed by default and in use. No user action required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so the problem was resolved by

```
sudo update-pciids
```

After that you have 2 options:

1. Upgrade to kernel 4.14.1

OR

2. Add `i915.alpha_support=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` in `/etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub`

Updating `pciids` appears to be essential for both options

Comment: Hmm even with kernel 4.14.1 it turns out you may still need i915.alpha_support=1